Nginx how to intercept requests to http:<ip>:8080 and redirect them to for example localhost:80/auth
I am trying to redirect any user opening an application running on my machine, to an nginx server. I have this configuration for ngins in the conf file:
This is what I tried, for example, redirecting requests from google.com to localhost:80.
    upstream google {
        server google.com;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name google.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            # Your own server's content or application
            index index.html;
        }
    }

But nothing happens. What am I missing?
